# Change Screen Timeout to Never

Tags: samsung-nexus-s, screen-timeout

Is it possible that I can change my screen timeout to never? I am using Nexus S. Currently, the maximum value I can set for screen timeout through settings is 30 minutes.

Comment: Just curious: Why? If you're watching a movie or something the app *should* keep the screen awake.

Comment: Because when I am at home, is it quite annoying that I have to keep pressing power button to turn on the display, if I receive frequent email/sms on and off.

Comment: I use and app called [Unlock with Wifi](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.benhirashima.unlockwithwififree) that removes the lock screen as long as I'm on my home network. Better than keeping the screen on all the time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are searching for this app [Keep Screen Lite](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.tni.KeepScreenLite). It allows you to keep your mobile always awake for some of the applications. You can set the applications to not to screen timeout.

Answer (score 6):

You can set it to stay on as long as it's plugged in.  To do that go to Menu -> Settings -> Applications -> Development and choose Stay Awake.

Answer (score 2):

Let me just warn you, the Nexus S has a Super AMOLED screen and you can burn in the images on the screen. I have burn-in of the Time and the notification bar on my screen. it is only noticeable when i have light colored wallpaper, but it is there.

Samsung even removed the "Stay Awake" option from the Galaxy S Vibrant line (possibly others as well) in their TouchWiz UI. The Nexus S will still have it, because it is a Vanilla Android.

The screen is also one of the biggest consumers of power, so if you leave your screen on all the time, when not charging, expect to see poor battery life.

Comment: Sorry. What do you mean by "burn in the images"?

Comment: see this article, it will explain better then I can. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screen_burn-in

Comment: Interesting, for how long did you left your screen on, so that it burned?