# Setting screen timeout when browsing

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, screen, browser, screen-timeout, reading

I know that it's a often asked question, however, none of the answers are applicable to me.

I read [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/7788/how-to-disable-screen-timeout-for-a-particular-program-only), [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4595/screen-timeout-when-reading) and [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/10223/change-screen-timeout-to-never) answers, but some apps (like Screebl or Keep Screen Lite) are non-existent already and some (Tasker) are not working for me.

The most proposed solution is Tasker, however I tried it and it messes my display settings which is even worse than the lack of dynamic timeout. It doesn't return timeout setting to default state which then drains my battery and is also very irritating. Seems to be a bug.

My question is: do you know a **native MM way** to dynamically set up timeout while browsing? Or maybe a web-browser app that have **built-in** ability to disable timeout?

I tried searching descriptions of apps, but this option is rarely highlighted, and, personal experience is highly appreciated. Have anybody met such app?

Comment: Built-in systems are not available I suppose. Have you tried out [Caffeine](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nl.syntaxa.caffeine)? Works absolutely great on my phone.

Comment: It bothers me that it wast updated last time in 2014, when they heard nothing about MM. Don't like to use abandoned apps.

Comment: The app is not quite "abandoned". 4.2 rating after 10 million downloads is not that bad. Anyways, let's hope someone else will provide you with some other option.

Comment: Ok, will try again according to your guide.

Comment: @Suncatcher Did it work?

Comment: As far as I can estimate now, it works. It looks like it reset to defaults after reading. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The most proposed solution is Tasker, however I tried it and it messes my display settings

I use [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) to keep my display time for longer when using certain apps, and it works perfectly. It's very possible that you might have missed a minor setting somewhere. Therefore, I suggest you try the steps below to set it up correctly.

1. download [Tasker.](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) (it is a paid app, but you can get a free trial version and see if you like it. It has much more than the options mentioned here)
2. Open the app and press on the '+' symbol on the bottom right of the screen. And press 'application'
3. Now select the apps in which you want the display to stay on for a long time. For example your browser app, or any other app. Select as many apps as you want for this action.
4. Press on the back button on your phone. Now it will ask you what you want to happen when you open those apps.
5. Press on 'new tasks'
6. Type a name for this task something like 'screen timeout 5 min'
7. In this new window, press on the plus symbol, and in the search bar type 'display timeout'
8. Press 'display timeout', and now under where it  says 'mins' choose the amount of time you want the screen to stay on for, while using the apps.
9. Press on the back button twice, and you should be brought back to the main page.
10. Long press on 'screen timeout 5 min' (or whatever you named this task) and press on 'add exit task' -> 'new task'
11. Give the new task a name something like 'screen timeout x seconds.'
12. Here, do the same as steps 7 and 8 just when setting the time, set it to the amount of time you want the screen to stay on while you're not using the selected apps.
13. Now, go back all the way to the main screen of Tasker and press on the check mark symbol on the top right. (If you don't see a check mark symbol, then don't worry about it)
14. Test to see that all is working by going to your home screen and see how long it takes for the screen to go to 'sleep' it should be the amount of time selected in step 12, then go into the selected apps and see how long the screen stays on.

Answer (score 0):

I use an app called Keep Screen On. Simple and very easy to use.

Comment: That's a pretty generic app name. Could you [edit] your answer and add a link to the app you mean? Otherwise people probably won't find the same one you're recommending.